# Find random $n$ combinations of values with a given sum

Tags: performance-tuning, random, recursion, algorithm

This problem is described in the related StackOverflow question: [Find all combinations of coins when given some dollar value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106929/find-all-combinations-of-coins-when-given-some-dollar-value).

I would like generate a list of $n$ combinations of values that sum up to a certain number. For example, these are 3 ways to obtain the number `100` using the values `{25, 50}`:

```
25*4
25*2 + 50*1
50*2
```

To calculate the combinations, I have adapted the recursive algorithm from python found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1005608&page=3&p=6349052#post6349052). My adapted code in Mathematica looks like this:

```
makeChange[value_Integer, denominations_List, soln_List, nsol_: 0] := 
 Module[{solution = soln, partial},
  If[nsol != 0 ∧ Length[solutions] >= nsol,
   Return[];
   ];
  If[value == 0,
   AppendTo[solutions, solution];
   Return[];
   ];
  If[denominations == {},
   Return[];
   ];
  With[{firstCoin = First@denominations, tail = Rest@denominations},
   With[{n = Floor[value/firstCoin]},
    Do[
     If[n - ix > 0,
      partial = Append[solution, {firstCoin, n - ix}],
      partial = solution
      ];
     makeChange[value - (n - ix)*firstCoin, tail, partial, nsol];
     , {ix, 0, n}];
    makeChange[value, tail, solution, nsol];
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

And can be called like this:

```
solutions = {};
makeChange[100, {25, 50}, {}, 3];
solutions // Column
```

> ```
> {{25,4}}
> {{25,2},{50,1}}
> {{50,2}}
> ```

Now, the code works ok but I have two major concerns.

1) It is slow when there are a large number of possible combinations. Can the performance be improved, maybe with memoization?

2) As it is, the algorithm is deterministic and will always return the same first $n$ solutions. Can the code be adapted to make it non-deterministic, so the solutions' order would be random? This will be useful when doing statistical analysis on a smaller sample of a very large set of solutions.

Note that I am not looking for solutions that only calculate a *number* of possible solutions. I need the actual solutions for statistical analysis. I am also not looking just for the *optimal* solution, I need to be able to calculate all of them.

**Update:**

Thanks to @Dr.belisarius' and @march's comments, I considered using the built-in [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html) and [`FrobeniusSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html).

The performance of `IntegerPartitions` is quite good with my test problem if the number of solutions is not too large (it uses a lot of memory):

```
t = Rationalize@{2.3, 3.06, 3.92, 4.1, 5.74, 7.8, 7.5, 8.5, 0.68, 0.72, 0.81, 0.92, 1.02, 1.07, 1.12};

AbsoluteTiming[
 solip = IntegerPartitions[1000/(GCD @@ t), All, t/(GCD @@ t), 100000];
]
```

> ```
> {0.882162, Null}
> ```

However, `FrobeniusSolve` is too slow to find even 100 solutions and seems to run forever.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 solf = FrobeniusSolve[t/(GCD @@ t), 1000/(GCD @@ t), 100];
]
```

> ```
> $Aborted
> ```

Both built-in functions are also deterministic.

Comment: `IntegerPartitions[100, 4, {25, 50}]` ?

Comment: Have you looked at `IntegerPartitions`? For instance, `IntegerPartitions[100, All, {25, 50}]` generates your first example. I expect that `IntegerPartitions` will be nice and optimized, but I'm not sure because I don't know enough about it, which is why for now I'm only posting a comment. As for randomizing the list, you could do `RandomSample`.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, @march `IntegerPartitions` is too memory-hungry for large integers, unfortunately.

Comment: Also, it's deterministic.

Comment: Also `FrobeniusSolve[{25, 50}, 100]`

Comment: @shrx. Making the algorithm generate a sample from the correct distribution sounds hard to me, because it's unclear how to do the sampling correctly, even in the case where we assume that each partition is considered to be equally likely. (I googled "generate random integer partition" and some hits came up on, for instance, StackOverflow, so perhaps that's an option.) That's why I suggested `RandomSample`. You can generate the entire list first (which obviously takes a long time so will only work for smaller numbers), then generate a random sample from the entire list of partitions.

Comment: @march the random sample from a larger set of solutions is not useful, as I could just use the whole set instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Probably have to go down the route of looking up algorithms for generating random integer partitions, then.

Comment: Check http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.00070.pdf algorithm 2 in page four. Don't know if it can be coded easily.

Comment: @PlatoManiac thanks, I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19829615/1420399

Answer (score 6):

Use [`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice.html) with [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)

```
denom = {penny, nickel, dime, quarter, half, dollar};
value = {.01, .05, .1, .25, .5, 1};

instance[total_, n : _Integer?Positive : 100] :=
 RandomChoice[FindInstance[
   denom.{1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100} == 
     100 total &&
    (And @@ Thread[denom >= 0]),
   denom, Integers, n]]

instance[1.67]

(*  {penny -> 62, nickel -> 0, dime -> 8, quarter -> 1, half -> 0, 
 dollar -> 0}  *)

denom.value /. %

(*  1.67  *)

instance[1.67]

(*  {penny -> 52, nickel -> 11, dime -> 1, quarter -> 0, half -> 1, 
 dollar -> 0}  *)

denom.value /. %

(*  1.67  *)

instance[2.33, 1000]

(*  {penny -> 78, nickel -> 9, dime -> 1, quarter -> 2, half -> 1, 
 dollar -> 0}  *)

denom.value /. %

(*  2.33  *)
```

Comment: I modified the code a bit to better suit the question, I hope it's ok. `FindInstance` is itself non-deterministic, so we don't need to wrap it in `RandomChoice`.

Comment: @shrx - I returned my answer to original. Your edits caused `instance` to return the same result for the same input rather than varying the result for each call. Recommend that you put your response in a separate answer.

Comment: That's interesting. I have checked the output for multiple solutions and it is different every time. But I didn't check the output for a single solution, where it appears the result will always be the same. Maybe it's worth opening a separate question about this.